ExecuteUpdate for dynamic entity
I am trying to use the ExecuteUpdate method with a dynamic entity. When using the following code snippet where my entity is dynamic, I get the following error:

Unable to cast object of type System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression to type System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression

How can I resolve this issue?
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x"); 
var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "MyProp"); 
var conversion = Expression.Convert(memberExpression, typeof(object)); 
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(conversion, parameterExpression).Compile();

await query.ExecuteUpdateAsync(c => c.SetProperty(lambda, newValue));

